# Regex "before text matching" in GoLang

Tags: javascript, regex, go

I have a piece of JavaScript code that I'm trying to replace with GoLang. The logic requires me to split the following string on ";" only when followed by "I" or "D":

```
I.E.viewability:-2;D.ua:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G920W8 Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36;D.G.city:Burnaby;D.G.zip:V5C;D.G.region:BC;D.G.E.country_code2:CA;
```

In JavaScript I accomplish this using:

```
/;(?=[ID]|$)/
```

My understanding is that GoLang uses this regex lib

https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

which clearly shows the above syntax (called `before text matching re`) as not supported.

What would be the correct way of achieving the same result in GoLang?

Comment: You could try using ```regexp.FindAllString```. Link => https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllString. This way, you could find the indexes where the regexp match occurs, and based on that split your string. Won't be straightforward like strings.Split() though :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may "reverse" the regex to *match* the strings you need. You want to match any 1+ chars other than `;` followed with `;` that are not followed with `I` or `D`.

Use

```
[^;]+(?:;[^ID;][^;]*)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w7zf2w/1)

**Details**:

- `[^;]+` - 1 or more chars other than `;`
- `(?:;[^ID;][^;]*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `;` - a `;`
  - `[^ID;]` - a char other than `I`, `D` or `;` (that is in order not to match empty values)
  - `[^;]*` - zero or more chars other than `;`

See a [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/ccd52O_rus).

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`[^;]+(?:;[^ID;][^;]*)*`)
    var str = `I.E.viewability:-2;D.ua:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G920W8 Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36;D.G.city:Burnaby;D.G.zip:V5C;D.G.region:BC;D.G.E.country_code2:CA;`

    for _, match := range re.FindAllString(str, -1) {
        fmt.Println(match)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
I.E.viewability:-2
D.ua:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G920W8 Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36
D.G.city:Burnaby
D.G.zip:V5C
D.G.region:BC
D.G.E.country_code2:CA
```